# HTML emails using python

Tags: python, html, email

I have a python script that downloads certain information from my database, to be used in emails to customers.

Currently I am pulling in the html as a string and replacing pre defined strings within the html, with my python variables. this feels like a very primitive way to do this.

I have found this: http://karrigell.sourceforge.net/en/pythoninsidehtml.html - however it is not quite what I'm looking for but nearly the right idea.

Is there a more efficient way of replacing values in my HTML email with my python variables to create a final email with all a users data, than just swapping them out in a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `emails` library. It supports HTML templates like Jinja.

A snippet from the [documentation](http://python-emails.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

```
from emails.template import JinjaTemplate as T

message = emails.html(subject=T('Payment Receipt No.{{ billno }}'),
                      html=T('<p>Dear {{ name }}! This is a receipt...'),
                      mail_from=('ABC', 'robot@mycompany.com'))

message.send(to=('John Brown', 'jbrown@gmail.com'),
             render={'name': 'John Brown', 'billno': '141051906163'})
```